# What's the use for the new dll "sunec.dll" file along with JAVA7

Tags: java, dll, release, java-7, sun

I just noticed there is one new dll file named `sunec.dll` since JAVA7.

I tried Googling a lot about this file but in vain.

Can anyone provide an introduction about this new file here??

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main reason is to enable Elliptic Curve Cryptography on **all** platforms. See the [JDK 7 Adoption Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/adoptionGuide/):

> **Elliptic Curve Cryptography (ECC)**
>
> A new native provider has been added to the JDK 7 release that provides several ECC-based algorithms (ECDSA/ECDH). Having an ECC provider also enables ECC-based JSSE ciphersuites on all platforms. Previously, only platforms with a native PKCS11 ECC implementation (e.g. Solaris) could use ECC-based ciphersuites out of the box. For more information, see [SunEC Provider's Supported Algorithms](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunEC) in the Java Cryptography Architecture Oracle Providers Documentation (JDK 7 Guides).

Comment: Note also that this library is licensed separately from the JDK, and it is under the LGPL.  So, be sure to take extra care if you ship the JRE in your product and keep this library intact.

Answer (score 3):

It's one of the crypto libraries, this particular one provides Elliptical Curve Cryptography as per [this page here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SunEC).